# Adding <TR> to a <TABLE> with .appendChild

Tags: javascript, html

Everytime I try to enter a new cell to the table it doesn't add the text in the **bowlersName** value. Is there something wrong with my Javascript code? It says "undefined".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */

    function addBowler() {
        var newBowler = document.getElementsByName('bowlersName').value;
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        var td = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
        td.innerHTML = newBowler;
        document.getElementById("bowlerList").appendChild(tr);
    }
    /* ]]> */
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- HEADER 1 & 2 -->
    <h1>Central Valley Lanes</h1>
    <h2>2008 Bowling Teams</h2>
    Bowler's name <input type="text" name="bowlersName" size="15" /><input type="button" value="Add Bowler" onclick="addBowler()" />

    <h2>Team Roster</h2>   
    <form action="FormProcessor.html" method="get">
        <table border="1" id="bowlerList">
            <tr>
                <td id="empty">Your team roster is empty</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Submit Roster" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: What says "undefined"? The console? The screen? An alert box? Please be more specific.

Comment: When you append rows to a table, you really need to find a `<tbody>` element in the `<table>` to append them to.

Comment: can I add this code after the newbowler variable? <input type="button" value="remove" onclick="removePlayer />

Answer (score 6):

Try to change this line:

```
td.innerHTML = (" + bowlersName + ");
```

To this:

```
td.innerHTML = "(" + bowlersName + ")";
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems

1. There is no variable named `bowlersName`, it should be `newBowler`
2. Your string concatenation is wrong, `(" + bowlersName + ")` should be `newBowler`

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/B7zte/4/)

```
function addBowler() { 
    var table = document.getElementById("bowlerList");
    var emptyRow = document.getElementById("empty");
    if(emptyRow){
        emptyRow.parentNode.removeChild(emptyRow)
    }

    var newBowler = document.getElementsByName('bowlersName')[0].value;
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var td = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    td.innerHTML = newBowler;
    table.appendChild(tr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But how do I delete the first <td></td> element when I enter a new cell? I want to remove the "Your team roster is empty" cell.

Comment: you can do that with a call like document.getElementById("bowlersList).removeChild("empty");

Comment: can I add this code after the newbowler variable?
<input type="button" value="remove" onclick="removePlayer />

Answer (score 1):

```
 <table class="table table-striped" id="dashTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">First</th>
                    <th scope="col">Last</th>
                    <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="task-row">    
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Now you can insert your rows using literal strings:

```
            data.forEach((element, i) => {
                console.log(element, i)
                var t = document.getElementById("dashTable");
                var r = document.createElement("TR");
                r.innerHTML = `
                                             <tr>
                                                <th scope="row">${i + 1}</th>
                                                <td>${element.text}</td>
                                                <td>${element.createdAt}</td>
                                                <td>${element.completed}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                    `
                t.tBodies[0].appendChild(r)
```