# Adding row to a table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am just doing a Javascript excercise which should add a row into a table. Html reads like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html><head><br><meta charset=utf-8 />   
</head><body>  
<table id="sampleTable" border="1">  
<tr><td>Row1 cell1</td>  
<td>Row1 cell2</td></tr>  
<tr><td>Row2 cell1</td>  
<td>Row2 cell2</td></tr>  
</table><br>  
<input type="button" onclick="insert_Row()" value="Insert row">   
</body></html>
```

And my script that doesn't work:

```
 function insert_Row(){
      var xTable=document.getElementById('sampleTable');
       for (i=0;i<=xTable.children.length;i++)
       {
        if(i===xTable.children.length)
        {
          xTable.createElement('tr');
          tr.innerHTML ='<td>cell1</td><td>cell2</td>'

        }

      }

    }
```

This is the correct solution:

```
function insert_Row()
{
var x=document.getElementById('sampleTable').insertRow(0);
var y = x.insertCell(0);
var z = x.insertCell(1);
y.innerHTML="New Cell1";
z.innerHTML="New Cell2";
}
```

I would like to understand what is wrong with my first solution? Why doesn't it create the  tag but throws error instead?

Comment: [stackoverflow.com - adding-tr-to-a-table-with-appendchild][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269652/adding-tr-to-a-table-with-appendchild

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269652/adding-tr-to-a-table-with-appendchild][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269652/adding-tr-to-a-table-with-appendchild

Comment: @adminez look at the help link to see how to post links in comments, it is not the same as answering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your `xTable.createElement` is not creating any child element.The  actual method is `document.createElement()`.There is no   `element.createElement`

again `parentnode.children` is accessing only the elements which is a direct children of table element which is `tBody` element.So, `parentnode.children.length`  is equal to 1 here.But it will increase after adding another tr element as it was not added to tbody element.***Thus it makes the for loop infinite***.I will discuss it shortly.

also you have to use `element.appendChild()` method to appedn the child you
   have already created.To add table cells don't use innerHTML,rather
   use [dom methods to do this things for you](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp)

The for loop in your code is getting ***infinite***, because after adding one ***tr*** element to your table, `xTable.children.length` is increased by one.So,every time the for loop is executed it finds that the length is increased and after adding another tr element it increases once again. So,it never gets any chance to **break**.Thus become infinite loop.So careful when  using for loop to add element to table

```
  var xTable=document.getElementById('sampleTable');

      var tr=document.createElement('tr');
      tr.innerHTML ='<td>cell1</td><td>cell2</td>'
      xTable.appendChild(tr);
```

Answer (score 6):

You never add the row to the table. The [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) does not attach itself to anything. You would need to use [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) or [insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore)

```js
var table = document.getElementById("sampleTable"),
    tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

for (var i=0;i<5;i++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var cell1 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell2 = document.createElement("td");
  cell1.innerHTML = i + "- 1";
  cell2.innerHTML = i + "- 2";
  row.appendChild(cell1);
  row.appendChild(cell2);
  tbody.appendChild(row);  
}
```

```html
<table id="sampleTable" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row1 cell1</td>
      <td>Row1 cell2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row2 cell1</td>
      <td>Row2 cell2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The first error, in execution, is that you try to call `xTable.createElement`. Element nodes do have a `createElement` method; document nodes do, so you would need to use `document.createElement('tr')` instead. And you need to assign its return value to a variable in order to do anything with the newly created element.

Moreover, you need to add the element to the document tree. If you add it to the table, there is a problem. You have loop that traverses all the children of the table, and appending a new child would make the loop infinite. The loop is actually not needed at all. To find the last child, you need not traverse all children; you just use the `children.length` property. But you don’t need even that; to append a row (which is what you are doing here, not really inserting), you simply call the `appendChild` method of the prospective parent.

There’s more. In HTML (strictly speaking, in HTML linearization only, not in XHTML linearization), a `tr` element is not a child of `table`. Browsers will insert `tbody` elements when needed so that a `tr` is a child of a `tbody` which is a child of `table`. This means that the value of `xTable.children.length` is 1; the table has just one child, a `tbody` element.

Thus, using the approach in your first code can be properly coded as follows:

```html
<table id="sampleTable" border="1">  
<tr><td>Row1 cell1</td>  
<td>Row1 cell2</td></tr>  
<tr><td>Row2 cell1</td>  
<td>Row2 cell2</td></tr>  
</table>
<p><input type="button" onclick="insert_Row()" value="Insert row">   
<script>
 function insert_Row(){
      var xTable = document.getElementById('sampleTable');
      var tr = document.createElement('tr');
      tr.innerHTML = '<td>cell1</td><td>cell2</td>';
      xTable.children[0].appendChild(tr); // appends to the tbody element
}
</script>
```

Comment: xTable.children.length is one for the first case.But after appending another tr element it will increase by one.Because tr will  not be added to tbody.If tr is added to current tbody element it will remain one every time

Answer (score 0):

Tables are special. They have special (optional) methods to add children. `TABLE` has [`insertRow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.insertRow) and `TR` has [`insertCell`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement.insertCell). They're especially useful if you want to add the row/cell somewhere not at the end.

Setting a `TR`'s `innerHTML` should work on most browsers, but probably not all.

(If you're building an entire table, create the HTML in JS and then set an `innerHTML`. It's much faster than creating separate `TR` and `TD`.)